# MST recursive construction on subgraph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum, greedy

MST denotes: Minimum Spanning Tree.

Given a Graph g = (V, E). Arbitrarily partitioned the vertices into 2  disjoint sets, V1 and V2. 
Let E1 is all edges with both incidents vertices in V1
Let E2 is all edges with both incidents vertices in V2
Let E3 is all edges with one incident in V1 one in V2

Now contruct a MST M1 on subgraph(V1, E1) and a MST M2 on subgraph( V2, E2). Then add the lowest weight edge in E3 that connected M1 and M2. Is this result in constructing a MST on the original graph g?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is no.

Consider the graph G: {Vertices: {A, B, C, D} Edges: {AB = 1, BD = 10, DC = 3, AC = 2}}. When it is divided as V1 = {A, C} V2 = {B, D} E1 = {AC} E2 = {BD} E3 = {AB, CD}, according to the description the MST is {AC, AB, BD}, while the true MST is {AB, AC, CD}.

Recall the Kruskal algorithm: Edges are sorted by weight in ascending order and the ones will not form a cycle with already exist edges in MST will be added one by one. MST is tree, so |E|-1 edges will be selected (assume there is no isolate vertices in the MST). If |E1| < |V1|-1 or |E2|<|V2|-1 and |E3|>1, then more than one edges in E3 will be added to the MST when the Kruskal algorithm is implemented on the whole graph G. If the MST is constructed from M1 M2 and the smallest edge in E3, it may lose some edges.

Also, if we implement the Kruskal algorithm on the whole graph G, more than one edges which are small in E3 may be added (we call them E3’). If we implement the Kruskal algorithm separately on V1 E1 an V2 E2, the edges which are larger than those in E3’ will be added to M1, M2. And only the smallest edge in E3 (E3’) will be added. So, the total weight of second MST is larger than the first one and it is not a true MST.

Are there any cases building up the MST separately is the same as building up it on the whole graph?

1. When E3 has only one edge:

   When the Kruskal algorithm is implemented on the whole graph G, this edge will be added to MST because it does not form a cycle with any edges. And it does not affect the decision on any other edges.
2. When M1, M2 are both connected tree which do not have isolate
   vertices and at least |E3|-1 edges in E3 are the largest edges in
   the E.

   When Kruskal algorithm is implemented on the whole graph, the smallest edge in E3 will be added to the MST. It does not affect the decision on any other edges in E1 or E2 added after it. Because it will not form cycle with any edges in E1 or E2. And the other edges in E3 will not be added because they are the last edges to be considered in Kruskal algorithm and they will form a cycle with already exist edges in MST.